# Defeating one is all it takes

Tags: wordplay

Hundreds of soldiers formed a line in front of me. Behind them was the prize.

The rightmost soldier proclaimed, "You might be able to defeat one of us, but that would be all it takes."

"How?" I asked.

"Use the note that sounds like how I smell," was his answer.

"Is this a game?" I asked.

"How did you know?" replied the soldier.

**How will I get past the soldiers?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I realise things might look bleak, but fear not - these soldiers are all pushovers, really...

> Because they are **dominoes**! The clue to their identity is given by '*the note that sounds like how I smell*', which indicates '**DO**' (the note C-natural in musical [Solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge)) and "**MY NOSE**" (i.e. how I smell).
>
>  The fact they are standing in a line is significant. Push the one on the end into the next and all of them will topple in succession (i.e. 'defeat one of us... that would be all it takes') - victory is yours!

Comment: Thanks! I will use your advice :)

Comment: "pushovers" XD nice pun

Comment: Nice puzzle, humorous solve. An enjoyable read.